# Sitecore Lucene Exclude Item From Index

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to allow a content editor to have the option to exclude items from a search page. There is a checkbox on the template being searched which indicates whether or not it should show up or not. I've seen a few answer that involve inheriting from Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler and overriding the AddItem method ([Excluding items selectively from Sitecore's Lucene search index - works when rebuilding with IndexViewer, but not when using Sitecore's built-in tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193990/excluding-items-selectively-from-sitecores-lucene-search-index-works-when-reb)). This does not seem to be hit when rebuilding indexes from the control panel though. I have been able to hit a method in Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler called RebuildFromRoot. Does anyone know exactly when the DatabaseCrawler method from that question is hit? I have a feeling I'll need to use both a custom SitecoreItemCrawler and DatabaseCrawler but I'm not positive. Any insight would be appreciated. I am using Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150621).

Comment: Would it be better for the  content editor to refine the search results rather than have them exclude items from the index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inherit from the default Lucene crawler implementation in Sitecore and override the `IsExcludedFromIndex` method, returning true to exclude the item from being indexed:

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace MyProject.CMS.Custom.ContentSearch.Crawlers
{
    public class CustomItemCrawler : Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler
    {
        protected override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, bool checkLocation = false)
        {
            bool isExcluded = base.IsExcludedFromIndex(indexable, checkLocation);

            if (isExcluded)
                return true;

            Item obj = (Item)indexable;

            if (obj["Exclude From Index"] != "1") //or whatever logic you need
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        protected override bool IndexUpdateNeedDelete(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
        {
            if (base.IndexUpdateNeedDelete(indexable))
            {
                return true;
            }

            Item obj = indexable;
            return obj["Exclude From Index"] == "1";
        }
    }
}
```

The `IndexUpdateNeedDelete` method is required to remove items from the index if an item in updated at a future date.

Use a patch file to replace the crawler for which ever indexes you need.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>    
    <contentSearch>

      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="sitecore_master_index">
            <locations>
              <crawler>
                <patch:attribute name="type">MyProject.CMS.Custom.ContentSearch.Crawlers.CustomItemCrawler, MyProject.CMS.Custom</patch:attribute>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
          ...
        </indexes>
      </configuration>

    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You will have to rebuild the indexes afterwards (from the control panel is fine) so that the items are excluded.

Comment: And I agree with @IanGraham comments about excluding from search results using a filter, rather than outright exclude form the index unless you have a specific reason for it.

Comment: The only real reason is that every time we hit the index we would be filtering with an extra parameter rather which should add some (as insignificant as it is) overhead. It definitely looks like that would have been easier though. I'd like to try what you suggested before going that route though.

Comment: You could take a look at the `contentSearch.getGlobalLinqFilters` pipeline, but that _may_ apply to **all** indexes **all** of the times. Also, take a look at the `indexing.filterIndex.inbound` pipeline for excluding items from the index, again this may apply globally across all indexes. BUT you may not want to this for core/master/web indexes since Sitecore uses these internally for it's own search in the CMS. If you go give the solution btw, you should create a custom index that utilizes this crawler.

Comment: Your solution seems to have worked but when I try to edit the checkbox I added I see an error saying that my custom class is missing the method IncludeTemplates. It does keep items I want to be excluded out of the index so it did do what I asked. I'm going to fall back to just indexing the checkbox value and filtering based on that though.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? I've used the above with no problem in SC8.0.6 and 8.1.3... I took a look the ContentSeach API and couldn't find any mention or methods called IncludeTemplates.