# Search Items without presentation details in sitecore

Tags: lucene, sitecore

Improve search performance.

We are currently on sitecore 8.1.3 in production and use Lucene Search to make the search work. We will be moving over to SOLR or Coveo search in near future. That said, we are trying to improve search functionality on our site.

In current scenario if a user searches on our site, Lucene search provides us with appropriate search results from sitecore content items. The results are a list of items in which some have presentation details where as some don't have presentation detail(which are basically datasource items, or pulled in multilist fields items). We displays results which have presentation details directly to user, however, the datasource items do not have presentation details attached to it, thus for such items we dispaly the items in which these respective items are referred as datasource items in presentation details, via sitecore link or are referenced in a multi-list field.

We are using `Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, false)` method to fetch the item where results items are referring to. We know this method is a heavy method. To improve the performance, we are filtering the items that are returned when we use `Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, false)` method. We select only the latest version of the item, we select an item only if the item has presentation details, we select only if the item is of same language as that of the context language. If the current item doesn't have presentation details, it will search for its related item with presentation details using the same function recursively. This logic or code that we have helps us to improve the performance at some level and yields the required results.

However this code slows down its performance if the number of search results is high. Say if I search for an item in which the Lucene search returns me say 10 items for it, our custom search code will then yield me say 100 related items(assuming the Datasource items of items found in the result can be reused across different items). The performance degrades when the Lucene search provides results with a huge count, say 500. In such scenarios we will be running our code recursively on 500 items and their related items. For better performance we have tried using LINQ query instead of foreach iterations wherever possible. The code works perfectly fine. We do get appropriate results, however the search slows down if the count is high for search items. Want to know if there is any more area where we can improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to improve the performance is to have a custom index that has the results you want to search and does not contain items that you do not want to return. In this way, your filtering is 'pre-done' during indexing.

The common way of doing is to use a computed field that will contain all the 'text' of the page (collating together content from datasources) so that the page's full contents are in a field in the index. This way, even if the text match would have been on a datasource, the page will still come back as a valid search result.

There is a blog from Kam Figy on this topic: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/

Note that in addition to the computed field, you will also need to patch in the field to the index using a Sitecore config patch file. Kam's blog shows an example of that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to index this data together to begin with, rather than trying to piece it together at runtime. You should also try to keep your indexes lean or use queries to restrict the results that are returned to only provide the relevant results.

I agree with the [answer from Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243891/661447) that a separate index is one of the best solutions, combined with a computed field that includes content from all referenced datasources.

Further, I would [create a custom crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339775/661447) which excludes items without any layout from the index. For an index which which is only used to provide results for site search, you only care about items with layout since only they have a navigable URL.

```cs
namespace MyProject.CMS.Custom.ContentSearch.Crawlers
{
    public class CustomItemCrawler : Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler
    {
        protected override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, bool checkLocation = false)
        {
            bool isExcluded = base.IsExcludedFromIndex(indexable, checkLocation);

            if (isExcluded)
                return true;

            Item obj = (Item)indexable;

            return obj.Visualization != null && obj.Visualization.Layout != null;
        }

        protected override bool IndexUpdateNeedDelete(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
        {
            Item obj = indexable;
            return obj.Visualization != null && obj.Visualization.Layout != null;
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you do not wish to create a separate index, or you only want to keep a single index (since you are using the Content Search API and require a full index for your component queries, or even just to minimise indexing speeds across multiple indexes) then I would consider [creating a custom computed field](https://www.symsoftsolutions.com/blog/2016/02/19/sitecore-custom-index-computed-field/) in the index which stores [true/false]. The logic is the same as above. You can then [filter in your search](https://soen.ghost.io/extending-the-default-contentsearch-functionality-in-sitecore/) to only return results which have layout.

The combination of including/combining the content of the datasourse items during indexing and only returning items with layout should result in much better performance of your search queries.